# Using URL-Scheme in application

Tags: ios, swift, url-scheme

I want to be using URL-Schemes in my application so when someone use the URL-Scheme, they unlock PRO version inside the application.

BUT, how can i make that the URL-Scheme can be used only once? So only 1 person can use the url scheme, and when the url scheme is used, it cannot be used again?

Comment: Maybe you should explain what you mean by ab "URL-Scheme". This sounds a bit strange... A url scheme is the protocol name noted at the beginning of a url. So for the url `http://stackoverflow.com` the url scheme would be `http`. I do not see how you can use that for some kind of authentication...

Answer (score 0):

Usaully, to unlock the pro version, you should be using in-app purchases!

Comment: I already am, but what if i want to give it away for free using url thing?

Comment: Just to make things clear, you want a way to to unlock your pro version only once inside your app, and after he unlocks the pro version he should not be available?